# Server setup and configuration

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, chown, drupal

I am tasked with the process of installing and configuring a LAMP server from scratch for hosting Drupal sites.

I have installed the LAMP stack but I'm experiencing multi-user editing problems.

Users are not permitted to write into files/directories created by someone else as the following message shows:

```
drush dl admin_menu
Directory /var/www/drupal-7.34/sites/all/modules/admin_menu exists,  [error]
but is not writable. Please check directory permissions.
```

I know this is ownership issue resolvable with the chown command but I would like to avoid chown-ing every time someone attempts to edit a file or download a module into a project the person didn't create.

**Can anyone give me details on how to configure my server so different users can access and edit websites files found in the /var/www directory?**

Answer (score 0):

Possibly create a group, chown all dirs to that group, and of course give at least rw permissions for group (x6x) with chmod

so:

1. `sudo groupadd drupal`
2. `sudo chown -R :drupal  /var/www/drupal-7.34/sites/all/modules/admin_menu`
3. `sudo usermod -G drupal <username>`
4. `sudo chmod -R +w /var/www/drupal-7.34/sites/all/modules/admin_menu`

P.S
make sure the user owning the web server service is also member of the group, unless owning all the dirs as user.

Answer (score 0):

Add users to the `www-data` group.